# Android Studio:select a particular word in a string of array

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to select a particular word in my input and put the selected word into array.

**EXAMPLE**
my input : *the quick brown fox*
i want to select the Word **Quick** because it started with letter Q and **fox** and its started with letter F and put the selected words to array .

I dont have any code right know

Comment: How would you want to select? please explain what exactly you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to split the message with space " " to get all words. After that with for check the words and if the word's first letter start with Q or F add it to list of string

```
String message = "the quick brown fox";
String[] ms = message.split(" ");
List<String> selectedWords = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < ms.length; i++) {
    if(ms[i].toLowerCase().startsWith("q") ||
            ms[i].toLowerCase().startsWith("f"))
        selectedWords.add(ms[i]);
}
```

Now you can read selected words like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < selectedWords.size(); i++) {
    etSelectedWord.setText(etSelectedWord.getText() + " " + selectedWords.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
String Name="the quick brown fox";
String[] Name_sp= Name.split(" ");
    String s1 = Name_sp[0];
    String s2 = Name_sp[1];///Quick
    String s3 = Name_sp[2];
    String s4 = Name_sp[3];///fox
```

Comment: thank you but it doesnt work